# Off Canvas Menu not sliding under Canvas

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, flexbox

**What I'm Making**

I'm trying to create a [Holy Grail Layout](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/)(Header,Footer,Navigation Sidebar,Canvas) using Flexbox in a web application. Although mine has no right Sidebar(just to note).

**The Effect Desired**

When the layout is squeezed into mobile the responsive adjustment would  be that the side Navigation panel should slide behind the Canvas and be accessible by a hamburger menu in the Header.

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-off-canvas-navigasi) is similar example of the effect although my Header wouldn't be sliding with it.

**The Issue Being Experienced**

I currently haven't added the hamburger sliding-I'm first trying to get the Navigation panel to slide underneath the Canvas when the layout is squeezed below 460 pixels in the width. **Yet**instead it appears to slide over(and even lose its height).

Here is a demo of mine failing [here](http://codepen.io/npineda/pen/XbNwaN)

**The HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Flexbox 01</title>
    <meta name="description" content="My Flexbox">
    <meta name="keywords" content="fex, box">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='myCSS.css'/>

</head>
<body>

<div class="flexbox-parent">
    <header class="header">Header</header>
    <div class="flex-main-container">
          <div class="navigation">Navigation</div>      
      <div class="canvas">Canvas</div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
 <script src="scripts/myJS.js"></script>

</body>
```

**The CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: pink;
}

.flexbox-parent
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 50px;
    /*margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;*/
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: hotpink;
}

.flex-main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.canvas {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid DeepSkyBlue;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: DeepSkyBlue;
}

.navigation {
    flex: 0 0 12em;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: yellow;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    /*margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;*/
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: aliceblue;
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {

  .navigation{
   position:absolute;
   width:12em;

  }





}
```

I've struggled with this one forever now and I could really use help. Thanks in advance for any ideas or solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need media queries: just use flexbox magic!

First, since the canvas seems to be the main content of the page, in the HTML it should appear first.

```html
<div class="canvas">Canvas</div>
<div class="navigation">Navigation</div>
```

In case you don't want to change the HTML, you can use `order`.

Then, use a multiline reversed row flow:

```css
.flex-main-container {
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
}
```

Since it's reversed, the navigation will appear at the left of the canvas, like you want.

Finally, add some `min-width` to the canvas:

```css
.canvas {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

If the screen isn't wide enough, navigation will be moved to the next line.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: pink;
}
.flexbox-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  /*margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;*/
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: hotpink;
}
.flex-main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.canvas {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid DeepSkyBlue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
}
.navigation {
  flex: 0 0 12em;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: yellow;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  /*margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;*/
  border: 1px solid aliceblue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="flex-main-container">
    <div class="canvas">Canvas</div>
    <div class="navigation">Navigation</div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```